# Logging onto Mac with RFID Cards

Tags: login, login-screen, authentication, authorization

I want my users to be able to login to their computers (which are Macs) using RFID or Magnetic Stripe. Can anyone recommend a way to implement this?

They all run Mavericks or Yosemite, and it doesn't matter whether they are connected to AD or not, as long as I can get cards to work! I will unbind the macs if necessary!

Thanks
Ed

Comment: What do you mean by "AD"? Oh, Active Directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few smart card readers (e.g. [this one](http://store.apple.com/us/product/H2312LL/A/scm-scr3500-smart-card-reader) on the Apple Store) that work with OS X.

For support of Smart Cards you may also want to check out [Smart Card Services](http://smartcardservices.macosforge.org) on MacOsForge.org, as highlighted by [this Apple Support document](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH13936) regarding smart cards on OS X Mavericks.

Comment: Could you recommend anywhere to buy written smart cards or a smart card reader/writer?

Comment: @EdG unfortunately, not really. I have only sparse experience with them (and it also depends on where you are on the world), but StackExchange & Google are your friends ;-) Also I can recommend the [Macenterprise.org forums](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/macenterprise) for such specific IT-admin questions.

Comment: The Apple support doc has been removed by Apple, it appears.

Comment: @ThomasTempelmann Strange, I can still see it; while it is now "archived" (article not getting updates in the future) it should still be available. Could you check again accessing the site, maybe with a different localization (e.g. https://support.apple.com/kb/PH13936?locale=de_DE )