# Using tap cards to log in

Tags: macos, login, smart-card

I would like to know if it’s possible to log into MacOS with a tap card like you would use for access control on facility doors etc.

I am familiar with smart cards and would strongly prefer my employees be able to log into POS Mac machines without having to insert a card.

These would all be linked to local accounts and all of my research leads me back here to an answer involving CAC and chip insertion at [Logging onto Mac with RFID Cards](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/135718/logging-onto-mac-with-rfid-cards)

Am I barking up the wrong tree here? Can you only login/unlock a Mac using a chip card if it’s inserted vs tapped and held?

Or am I missing something beyond obvious? Because I of course see touch-and-hold chip reading for credit cards every day on pay terminals.

Thank you for your insights.